# Is it possible to have a dynamic path as part of a jsp include

Tags: jsp, include, struts, include-path

I have a include file in my jsp

```
    <%@ include file = "includes/testinclude1.jsp" %>
```

Test Include1 contains struts tags, and therefore needs to be pulled in and compiled. Which works ok. Is there a way to make the path for this file be dynamic in any way or am I looking at a rethink in terms of design?

Comment: you want testinclude1.jsp to be dynaming?

Comment: did you mean something like `<%@ include file = "includes/${pageToInclude}" %>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can the `<jsp:include page="...">` tag instead of the static `<%@ include %>` which only works for static references.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is curious, I used a struts include tag, based on artbristols answer and managed to make it dynamic with OGNL. Thanks for all your input.

```
<s:include value="includes/templates/%{post.template.name}.jsp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

yes

```
<%
    String usuarioTipo = uDTO.getNombreGrupo().toLowerCase();
    String menu = "../WEB-INF/../jspf/".concat(usuarioTipo).concat("/menu.jspf");
%>
<jsp:include page ="<%=menu%>"/>
```