# include file directive not working in linux sever

Tags: linux, apache, jsp, tomcat, directory

My problem is, i have included a page using the code

```
 <%@include file="../include/dbconnection.jsp"%>
```

My page resides in a sub directory of public_html but when i load my page it shows the following exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(23,1) File "/../include/dbconnection.jsp" not found
```

But this code works fine in my development system(which is windows) i use a linux server for my website. Is this a problem with file separator or file permission issues? what could be the problem?

Comment: Unlikely is a permission issue (at least for now). If it says `file not found`, that's probably the case. I don't understand why the leading `/` in `/../include/dbconnection.jsp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer in the post below which is using `<jsp:include page="...">` , the `<%@include` only works with static references.

[Is it possible to have a dynamic path as part of a jsp include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092386/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-path-as-part-of-a-jsp-include)